# Returning future list in Play for Scala json

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.5

Apologies if this is a simple question. I need to return the Json structure in the `Action.async` method, however I'm not sure how to create a future that embeds a list that's already a future. Any suggestions?

```
case class Clazz (a: Int, b: Int)

def index = Action.async { 
       val json = JsObject(Seq(
            "x" -> JsString("1"),
            "list" -> Json.toJson(getList) // this line does not compile
       ))
       Ok(json)
}


def getList = Future {
    val c1 = Clazz (1,1)
    val c2 = Clazz (2,2)
    val list = List(c1,c2)
    list
}
```

UPDATE:

Added the following Writes object:

```
  implicit val cc: Writes[Clazz] = (
      (JsPath \ "a").write[Int] and
      (JsPath \ "b").write[Int] 
  ) (unlift(Clazz.unapply))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use the `map` function to get a new Future with the expected content:

```
def index = Action.async { 
  val eventualList: Future[List[Clazz]] = getList
  eventualList.map { list: List[Clazz] =>
    val json = JsObject(Seq(
      "x" -> JsString("1"),
      "list" -> Json.toJson(list) 
    ))
    Ok(json)
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm getting the following error in the `Ok(json)` line: `Cannot write an instance of scala.concurrent.Future[play.api.libs.json.JsObject] to HTTP response. Try to define a Writeable[scala.concurrent.Future[play.api.libs.json.JsObject]]` I added the Writes class (see update) and still have the problem

Comment: I made a mistake in my answer (I made you return a Response containing a future instead of a Future[Response]). It is fixed now.

Answer (score 3):

I usually prefer the for/yield syntax, so that if you need to add more Futures later you can easily extend without deeply nested maps and flatMaps.

```
def index = Action.async {
   for {
       list <- getList
   } yield {
       val json = JsObject(Seq(
            "x" -> JsString("1"),
            "list" -> Json.toJson(list)
       ))
       Ok(json)
    }
}
```

Comment: your answer is also helpful, unfortunately I can only mark one correct answer